# Ada library initialisation/elaboration and GPR directives : can't find elaboration symbol

Tags: libraries, ada, symbols, elaboration

I am trying to produce an Ada library for iOS.
However, it is necessary to perform the Ada elaboration manually.

I know that the compiler can produce an init symbol, that can be later imported and used. However, with the following GPR definition, it is not produced (the `nm` command  does not list it). The naming is supposed to be `<libname>init` with `<libname>` corresponding to the value defined in the GPR directive `Library_Name`

The GPR is defined in the following fashion (this one is windows/style -see DLL references-, but the problems also applies when producing for iOS on a Mac):

```
project adalib is
    for Languages use ("Ada");
    for Source_Dirs use (project'Project_Dir & "./src");
    for Library_Kind use "static"; --"static" on iOS will produce a .a file
    for Library_Name use project'Name; -- will produce "libadalib.a"
    for Library_Dir use project'Project_Dir & "./lib";
    for Library_Src_Dir use project'Project_Dir & "./includes";
    -- define your favorite compiler, builder, binder, linker options
end adalib;
```

I'm missing it : how to produce that symbol ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.
My GPR was missing this simple directive:

```
    for Library_Interface use ("mypackage"); -- put whatever packages you want to expose, without .adb/.ads since we're talking about packages
```

With the above directive, I can find the `adalibinit` symbol via `nm` command.
When I import it in my ada code, I can also use it, see :

```
package body mypackage is
    procedure Init_My_Lib
    is
       -- I want to call elaboration;
       pragma import (C, ada_elaboration, "adalibinit");
    begin
       ada_elaboration;
       -- further code
    end Init_My_Lib;
-- rest of package
```

So, the full GPR should be:

```
project adalib is
    for Languages use ("Ada");
    for Source_Dirs use (project'Project_Dir & "./src");
    for Library_Kind use "static"; -- will produce a .a file
    for Library_Name use project'Name; -- will produce "libadalib.a"

    for Library_Interface use ("mypackage"); -- <=== THIS IS HERE

    for Library_Dir use project'Project_Dir & "./lib";
    for Library_Src_Dir use project'Project_Dir & "./includes";
    -- define your favorite compiler, builder, binder, linker options
end adalib;
```

Comment: It’d be usual for `Library_Src_Dir` to be different from `Library_Dir` .. e.g. `"./include"`. But if it works .. !

Comment: Ok, now it is fixed